# Xamarin Forms - Pass Scope-Injected service from tabbedpageviewmodel to the viewmodels of the pages

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, arguments, tabbedpage

In my xamarin forms application I have a tabbedpage with behind it a viewmodel. This viewmodel behind injects a service with dependency injection. That service is scoped. It should be scoped for the tabbedpageviewmodel. But the tabs should also make use of that scoped service. How can I achieve this?

Should I pass the service to the tabbedpages-viewmodels?

Singleton is not an option, because I work with notifications, the tabbedpageviewmodel can accur multiple times in the navigationstack, and the service should be different then.

Comment: It would be better to create a  `BaseViewModel` . Then define a bool property  to confirm if need to pass service to its subclass .\

Comment: But how do I get the service there? I mean, people say that you shouldn't pass objects from tabs to tabs. I want each tab in the tabbedpage to have the shared object, it shouldn't be singleton because that would be project wide, I want it to be scoped to the tabbedpage only..

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the code and what you have done , so that people can understand the problem better .

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248865/xamarin-forms-pass-data-from-tabbed-page-to-child-tabs) was effectively a duplicate of this one. If you can respond to @LucasZhang to provide what has been asked for, I am sure that will be appreciated.